# Output HTML only on individual post view

Tags: plugins, posts, customization

I am looking for a way to output some html (javascript actually) on a post view only and not on a main page, tag, category view (where WP outputs several posts).

E.g it would be output on this page

blog.yourdomain.com/2012/05/some-post/

But not on
blog.yourdomain.com/
blog.yourdomain.com/category/xxx/
blog.yourdomain.com/tag/yyy/
etc.

**The HTML to be output is different for each post**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eugene's answer was a little over complex for my needs so here's what I did (though +1 to Eugene as it got me looking in the right places)

I first added **a custom field called singlePostHTML** to the posts that I wanted to add script to - put the script in the value.

[Wordpress - Using Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Custom_Fields#Usage)

I then edited **single.php** (as this template is used only when you're only displaying a single post, rather than multiple posts on home page or archive/category/search views).

[Wordpress - template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview)

And added the following

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'singlePostHTML',true); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load your js only on page/post view you can do it like this:

```
function myplugin_enqueue_scripts() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->is_single ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js', ... );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Gotcha - but this would be same for all pages. Do you know of any plugins that do this and allow user to put different html in on each page via normal edit functionality?

Comment: To do *anything* on a per-post basis, you'll need to define **custom post meta data**, to be used in your script output.